# Disable onSlideChangeEnd listener

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I would like to disabled my **onSlideChangeEnd** callback on my Swiper component.

If a user clicks on the arrows then I want to execute my onSlideChangeEnd callback method, however if I programatically want to slide to a particular image I do not want the onSlideChangeEnd called. Otherwise I get messy listener loop situations.

How do I do this?

I was thinking of having some kind of flag. If this flag is set to false, then the callback code is not executed, like so :

```
    galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top-product-view', { //'.gallery-top'
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 10,
        onSlideChangeEnd: function (swiper) {
            if(someFlag)
                doIt();

        }
    });
```

However the callback object seems to reference the old variable value. The 'someFlag' seems to be somewhat random when I use it like this :

```
    someFlag= true;

    galleryTop.slideTo(key);

    someFlag= false;
```

Am I missing something fundamental in how I should disable listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to swiper documentation ( http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/ ) you can pass third param `runCallbacks` as `false` to prevent callbacks execution:
`galleryTop.slideTo(key, speed, false);`

Comment: perfekt. what is the default speed? 1 second?

Comment: default speed is 300 (300ms)